# Goes to grub rescue after removing the partition with linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, grubrescue

I deleted the partition that had Ubuntu on it to get rid of dual boot, and now every time I try to boot to windows it goes to grub rescue, saying

```
error: no such device 22623f...
```

When I type `ls` is gives me

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1) (hd2)
```

When I type `ls (hd0,msdos1) /boot` it tells me that the filesystem is unknown.

If I boot from my USB with a usbnetbootin, it tells me that it `Could not find the ISO ${iso_path}` it says I can fix this by logging into Windows and running `chkdsk /r` but I cant do that for reasons that you know.

Honestly I have no clue what I'm doing and I've just been trying to follow other tutorials on here.

Comment: Do you have a Windows Recovery or Installation CD/USB?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the past where I messed with my partition scheme.

What worked for me was reinstalling Ubuntu on one of the partitions. Doing this created a fresh install of grub which in turn recognized all my partitions normally.

You might also want to try using a Boot-Repair:
[Getting Boot-Repair instrucions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)